# Sync database from rest API

Tags: java, database, synchronization

I am writing spring boot microservice, which would read data from clients REST Api. There will be a hourly job to check if data from clients REST api and database are same.

Is there any library to calculate difference between objects ? In rest api model we do not have any last modified property and it is not possible to have it. How would You solve this problem? Do I need to write any custom difference mechanism which checks each object if exists in db. It can be little slow because or huge record quantity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One possible approach: use SQL MERGE, add DB indexes on significant columns for 
better performance.